# Binary cast está disponível no PHP?

Tags: php, cast, binary

O PHP tem um `cast` (que até então eu não conhecia), chamado `binary`.

Exemplo do [Manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.type-juggling.php):

```
$binary = (binary)$string;
$binary = b"binary string";
```

De acordo com o Manual do PHP:

> (binary) - converte para string binária

Eu vi que um usuário ainda postou o seguinte:

> Cast a string to binary using PHP < 5.2.1
>
> (converter uma string para binário em versões anteriores ao PHP 5.2.1)
>
> `$binary = unpack('c*', $string);`

Com o teste que realizei no PHP 5.6, o resultado foi o seguinte:

```
$string = "My String";

$binary = (binary)$string;
$binary = b"binary string";

var_dump($binary); // string(13) "binary string"
```

Ou seja, retorna o mesmo valor da string (mesmo com o cast para `binary`).

A dúvida é: essa funcionalidade realmente está disponível (sendo *bug* do meu PHP) ou será apenas uma implementação futura (como dizem por aí: "No PHP 6")?

Comment: Como diz no manual: *(binary) - converte para string binária (PHP 6)*

Comment: @JorgeB. somente da doc em português está assim.

Comment: @JorgeB. É porque tem uma informação onde um usuário diz: _"PHP 5.2.1 <". Ou seja, dá a entender que já deveria funcionar

Comment: É verdade, @gmsantos. E tem mais _"(binary) casting and b prefix forward support was added in PHP 5.2.1"_ parece-me soar como _"foi implementado o suporte ao prefixo `binary`, mas não vai funcionar ainda".kkkkk

Comment: Aqui parece que não acontece nada a string: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/392dde9694e267a9d4e2e687e602e21097faa725

Comment: Vamos ver agora uma resposta oficial. Vamos ver o que o pessoal do manual tem a nos dizer nesse [Bug Reporting](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68919)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguindo as instruções do @gmsantos, criei esse [Bug Reporting](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68919&edit=2) lá no PHP.

De acordo com a resposta do usuário identificado como nikic@php.net, o motivo do `binary` não funcionar como esperado é o seguinte:

> (binary) is a forward compatibility token for the now abandoned "PHP 6". It
>   behaves the same way as doing a (String) Cast in "PHP 5".

Se alguém puder me ajudar a traduzir, agradeço. Mas eu vou dar uma interpretação (e não uma tradução):

> Isso é uma palavra-chave que foi adicionada em antecipado para o (agora abandonado)
>   PHP 6. O cast para `binary` se comporta da mesma forma que cast para `string` no PHP 5.

Comment: Talvez isso seja adicionado no futuro, ou cabe uma ressalva na documentação.

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro o manual diz que estará disponível no PHP 6 (que é uma versão que morreu). Ou outra versão já que até nisto o PHP é uma bagunça. Então você não poderá testar agora.

Este tipo de operação não deveria ser um *cast*. Mas é o PHP, já deveríamos estar acostumados.

Você está mudando o valor obtido com o *cast*. Não consigo imaginar porque. Por isto deu o resultado mostrado. Se tirar a nova atribuição depois do *cast*, em tese daria o resultado esperado se ainda corrigir um outro erro.

Não há exemplos reais de como isto funcionará então é complicado entender qual será a forma, vou chutar aqui o que talvez seja:

```
$string = "10011101";
$binary = (binary)$string;
$binary = b"10011101";
```

Nos dois casos o número será um inteiro valendo 157. Imagino eu.

Em PHP 5.2.1 dá para fazer de outra forma, não desta.

Eu já lhe falei da qualidade do manual, especialmente da versão em português. Pode ser que isto nem esteja presenta na próxima versão do PHP. Pode ser até que isto foi discutido mas nunca decidiram colocar na linguagem. Não confie em especulações.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/EB6cM5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/BinaryNotation). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Syntax/BinaryNotation.php).

Comment: Apesar de gostar muito do `PHP`, as vezes acho que ele tem muita gambiarra e muita coisa que não segue um padrão. Exemplo: `isset` e `is_null`, para mim, deveria seguir um padrão de escrita como `isset` e `isnull`. Entre muitas outra coisas!

Comment: @bigown o problema é que no manual em EN diz que já está a funcionar.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters indo por ai teríamos conversa para meses ou anos ;)

Comment: Eu gostava do PHP até descobrir que ele é uma desgraça. @JorgeB. eu vi depois, mas não está funcionando segundo todos os testes que eu fiz. Ou seja, funciona a sintaxe, mas não produz resultados http://ideone.com/CnTAQE

Comment: Vou marcar como resolvido. Já sei por experiência própria que o PHP tem dessas coisas: Criar um recursos que, porém, ainda não está implementado (para quem não sabe, ocorre o mesmo para a constante `INPUT_SESSION` na implementação do `filter_input`). Veja essa [gambiarra](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php)

Comment: Sim @bigown obtive exatamente os mesmos resultados. O PHP tem uma montanha desses pormenores que são uma desgraça completa. Tem também a vantagem de que, sem bem utilizado (utilizador consciente), ser uma ferramenta muito boa!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters há mais casos no `filter_input` que não funcionam.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters se o (binary) não funciona como deveria já tentou informar como um [bug](https://bugs.php.net/)?

Comment: Não ainda! mas é uma ótima ideia. Talvez isso ajude no progresso (que tanto reclamamos) da linguagem!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters acho que caberia como uma nova resposta explicando o por que de não funcionar ou o uso correto.